# Commutative operation - no simplifications

Tags: associativity

Suppose we have a set with an associative operation, but we don't know the set is a group. Therefore no simplifications are possible. We want to prove that if there exists $n \geq 2$ such that for any two elements $x,y$ in the set we have $(xy)^n = yx$, then the operation is commutative.

---

We can prove pretty fast that all the squares commute. Just multiply with $x$ in the right side and get
$$ yx^2 = (xy)^nx=x(yx)^n = x^2y$$

Then it is possible to prove that for $n$ even we have the desired conclusion. We have $(xy)^{n^2}=xy$ so if $n = 2k$ then
$$ xy = (xy)^{4k^2} = x(yx)^{2k^2}yxyx... = (yx)^{2k^2}(xy)^{2k^2}$$
since in the last expression we can commute the terms, which are squares, we may permute $x$ and $y$. The same trick does not work for $n$ odd, and for the moment I cannot find a good working argument.

> How would you solve this problem?

Comment: "We want to prove that if there exists $n \geq 2$ such that for any two elements $x,y$ in the set and  then if $(xy)^n = yx$ then the operation is commutative" - this is not a valid English sentence, and it makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the sentence after I wrote it, and left some bad parts in...